# How to Declare Regex string in global resource dictionary in xamarin forms App.xaml?

Tags: regex, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried to declare a regex as global resource but getting error as shown in attached image.

I just want to keep it in here instead of anywhere else.

[image]

Comment: Do not post code/xaml/errors/etc... as images, post them as formatted text within your question.

Comment: Searching this issue, it seems `" '  <   >  &` is invalid XML character in xaml file. You could achieve validation like this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/validation

Comment: thanks for reply, i know other ways to use it. I am just checking if it can be done in XAML

Comment: You can refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml, If you use `" ' < > &` In xaml directly, it will make some issues.

Answer (score 1):

#### Assuming a XAML namespace of `sys` for System:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

#### Then:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <sys:String x:Key="EmailPattern">... some regex patterm ...</sys:String>         
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

#### Usage:

```
if (Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("EmailPattern", out object regexPattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(regexPattern);
}
```